# Office 2013 vba Calendar mscomctl ocx

Tags: jquery, vba, calendar, ms-office, ocx

If you passed to the new version of Ms Office 2013 (or greater) you've probably found that the calendar control of your VBA application is no more reachable.
The unique solution is to install the OCX manually (or via a setup) but if you doesn't have administrator right it could be problematic, above all, if you have multiple clients.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a simple workaround. 
If I'm not mistaken, we all have a common component which is the "WebBrowser".
I'll show you now (mini tutorial) how to replace the calendar component.

## Tutorial

- Go to vba Editor  (Alt + F11)
- Create a new UserForm (you can change the name with 'calendarPicker')
- Open "Tools box"
- Right click over the "Tools box" and choose "Extra componant" in the menu
- Choose on the list "Microsoft Web Browser" then ok. Now you found a new icon on the tools box.
  [image: Extra componant] 
  [image: Tools Box]
- Drag and drop this new component in Userform.
- Add a command button on Userform.
  [image: UserForm]
- Open UserForm code window and put this code:

  ```
  Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
  Dim HTML  As HTMLDocument
  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
      Set objIE = Me.WebBrowser1
      WebBrowser1.Navigate ("http://YourWebSiteAddress/index.html")
  End Sub
  Private Sub ExtractDate()
      Set HTML = objIE.Document
      If Not HTML Is Nothing Then
          For Each elc In HTML.all.tags("input")
              mydate = elc.getAttribute("value")
          Next
      End If
      Me.Hide
  End Sub
  Private Sub cmdSelectDate_Click()
   Call ExtractDate
  End Sub
  ```
- After that you need to create a index.html file with this code.

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
     $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="width: 80%;">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- If you have a web site publish this page (index.html) and change this value "YourWebSiteAddress" with your web site in vba code :

  ```
     WebBrowser1.Navigate ("http://YourWebSiteAddress/index.html")
  ```

You can see the result 
[image] 
After Clicking on the input box you can choose a date. 
[image]

The last thing to do is to share the value selected in a module.vb thereby the caller can get the value.

That's all!
And you can put any Jquery component!